# nginx alternative for apache's "ProxyPassMatch" - proxypass configuration

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

i'm an absolutly newbie with server dev and have a simple problem: i went from apache reverse proxy to nginx reverseproxy. My Apache sites-available-Config (shortened) was:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

   <VirtualHost *:443>

      ProxyPassMatch (.*)(\/jarvis-socket)$ "ws://192.168.178.111:8400/$1$2"
      ProxyPass / http://192.168.178.111:8400/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.178.111:8400/
      <Proxy *>
         Order deny,allow
         Allow from all
         AuthType Basic
         AuthName "Password Required"
         AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
         Require valid-user
      </Proxy>
   </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

it locates to an local webapplication with http and websocket and this conf is working fine on apache.

Now i want some similar configuration for nginx for same purpose. What conf i've tried on nginx reverse proxy server is:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  ''      close;
}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name sub.domain.com;
  
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.178.111:8400;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
  }
}
```

it loads the webapp, but it seems like is not connecting with websocket service, so my nginx config needs some equivalent to apache's "ProxyPassMatch".

Can someone help me please and provide me a valid nginx server config snipped with something like `ProxyPassMatch (.*)(\/jarvis-socket)$ "ws://192.168.178.111:8400/$1$2"` in it? Thanks a lot and have a nice day <3

Comment: Note: This is a question about nginx - even though you're using Apache-syntax to describe what you'd like to see, the question is not about Apache httpd - please don't add those tags _again_. Also notice [help/on-topic], as this is rather configuration- than programming-related.